# Create documentation for *.xaml files with Doxygen

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, doxygen, uwp-xaml

I am currently trying to document my UWP-Project and was wondering if it is possible with doxygen to comment the *.xaml files?

I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29390238/doxygen-documentation-for-wpf) but it didn't work and I don't have enough reputation to comment on the solution.

Anyone got an idea or an alternative to doxygen where it is posible to create a documenation for *.xaml files?

Comment: Can you please clarify the scenario a bit more? There are solutions out there that extract documentation from a source file (though I am not sure it is common to extract documentation from a .xaml file - since you cannot really export any types/properties etc. without the .xaml.cs file where you could add documentation). But were you expecting a solution that would add documentation to your code?

Comment: I was looking for a solution that exports comments(or something similar) made in .xaml files to a documentation, for example a HTML generated documentation with doxygen.
I got doxygen to recognize the .xaml files with the solution i mentioned, but it didn't export any comments to the documentation.

cheers

Comment: Have you tried an aporoach similar to this post?https://stackoverflow.com/a/9631747/1480960